# Error al instalar el método maatwebsite/excel en Laravel

Tags: laravel, composer, php8

He instalado composer en mi proyecto y me decía que necesitaba el método  `maatwebsite/excel`, entonces lo instalé con `composer require maatwebsite/excel` pero de ahí me salió este error:

> *BadMethodCallException
> Method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::share does not exist.
> at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Macroable/Traits/Macroable.php:113*

Comment: Posiblemente el método `share()` no esté disponible en tu versión de Laravel. Intenta actualizar Laravel a una versión que sea compatible con la biblioteca `maatwebsite/excel`, o también checa los requerimientos de **[esta documentación](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/getting-started/installation.html)**.

Comment: como actualizo eso y como veo la version de laravel

Comment: no puede hacer nada osea trato de actualizar borro todo el vendor el composer.lock